# Which function has the same behaviour as collect but keep the elements that do not satisfy the predicate

Tags: scala, predicate, higher-order-functions

I am looking for a function that looks like `collect`. This function must keep the element that do not satisfy the predicate.
This behaviour be could expressed using `map`. Example :

```
@ (0 to 10).map{
      case e if e > 5 => e * e
      case e          => e // I want to keep elements to does not satisfy the predicate !
  } 
res3: collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[Int] = Vector(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 36, 49, 64, 81, 100)
```

I would like to be able to write this function like this :

```
@ (0 to 10).map{
      case e if e > 5 => e * e
  } 
scala.MatchError: 0 (of class java.lang.Integer)
  $sess.cmd4$$anonfun$1.apply$mcII$sp(cmd4.sc:1)
  $sess.cmd4$$anonfun$1.apply(cmd4.sc:1)
  $sess.cmd4$$anonfun$1.apply(cmd4.sc:1)
  scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
  scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
  scala.collection.immutable.Range.foreach(Range.scala:160)
  scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:234)
  scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.map(Traversable.scala:104)
  $sess.cmd4$.<init>(cmd4.sc:1)
  $sess.cmd4$.<clinit>(cmd4.sc:-1)
```

Unfortunately, I have not found a function that takes a `PartialFunction` to avoid `MatchErrors`.

Do you know a function with such a behaviour ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is a pre-defined method that does what you want, but you can use a `PartialFunction`'s `.applyOrElse` to do it:

```
scala> implicit class MySeq[A](r: Seq[A]) {
         def mapIfDefined(f: PartialFunction[A, A]): Seq[A] = {
           r.map(f.applyOrElse[A, A](_, identity))
         }
       }

scala> (0 to 10).mapIfDefined{
         case e if e > 5 => e * e
       }
res1: Seq[Int] = Vector(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 36, 49, 64, 81, 100)
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm mistaken, `collect` does exactly what you're asking:

```
scala> List(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10).collect {
     |   case e if e > 5 => e * e
     |   case e => e
     | }
res0: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 36, 49, 64, 81, 100)
```

Comment: I agree. `collect` and `map` (cf. my first code snippet) can do the job here. But my goal was to avoid this line : `case e => e`.

Comment: Why not just write `List(...).map { e => if(e > 5) e * e else e }`, then? I think it makes more sense than using an implicit `mapIfDefined` method to replace a simple `else` clause.